# NSView - userInteractionEnabled equivalent

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

Is there reliable/official way to completely disable user interaction with the view? Similar SO questions only suggest intercepting mouse events, but I'm looking for a complete solution, which will disable all interactions in view and it's descendants, including:

- mouse events
- trackpad
- keyboard focus/events
- accelerator keys
- voice input
- mind control techniques
- whatever other official way for user to spawn control events from the UI

The view (and it's descendants) should also immediately lose keyboard/mouse focus once interaction is disabled.

This should be similar to what `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:options:completionHandler:` does without `NSViewControllerTransitionAllowUserInteraction` flag, but I can't find a way to do that outside an animation.

**Update:**
The other way to describe what I'm looking for is: view must act totally like it's hidden, but still be drawn on screen.

Comment: Disable the controls if you want to disable all interactions.